# Java 17 compiler is slower than Java 8 compiler

Tags: java, performance

I have to compile some classes in my program, and it seems that the Java 17 compiler is way more slower than the Java 8 one.

- System : Windows 11 (tested on several computers)
- JDK 17 : 17.0.10
- JDK 8 : 1.8.0.333
- There is no problem on Linux.

In each version, I use the JDK embedded compiler by calling `ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();` and the standard file manager by calling `compiler.getStandardFileManager(..)`

In my real project, this difference can be an issue as I have to compile a lot of much more complex classes.

Has anybody the same problem?
Any idea of what's going on?

As a test, I have made 10 very simple classes (basically beans with primitive variables and set and get methods), which need no extra classes or jars to compile.

I've made a class that compile these 10 beans, using a loop to compile each file one another.
The total amount of compilation time is about 50 % higher with Java 17 than with Java 8.

I have run this test a lot of time, with the same result.

Here is an example of the output:

```
JDK 17 Compiling several classes using JavaCompiler directly
        compiling Alpha.java=322 ms
        compiling Beta.java=38 ms
        compiling Delta.java=34 ms
        compiling Epsilon.java=27 ms
        compiling Gamma.java=27 ms
        compiling Iota.java=25 ms
        compiling Lambda.java=23 ms
        compiling Phi.java=24 ms
        compiling Pi.java=25 ms
        compiling Zeta.java=19 ms
Total 564 ms
```

```
JDK 8 Compiling several classes using JavaCompiler directly
        compiling Alpha.java=259 ms
        compiling Beta.java=15 ms
        compiling Delta.java=15 ms
        compiling Epsilon.java=14 ms
        compiling Gamma.java=15 ms
        compiling Iota.java=12 ms
        compiling Lambda.java=11 ms
        compiling Phi.java=13 ms
        compiling Pi.java=11 ms
        compiling Zeta.java=13 ms
Total 378 ms
```

My test class:

```java
public class CompileTest {

    public void doCompile() {
        FilenameFilter ff = new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".java");
            }
        };
        System.err.println();
        System.err.println("JDK 8 Compiling several classes using JavaCompiler directly");
        JavaCompiler compiler=ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager=compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, Locale.getDefault(), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"));
        try {
            String sourceDir = "<source directory>";
            String[] classes = new File(sourceDir).list(ff);
            long total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < classes.length; i++) {
                String path = sourceDir+"\\"+classes[i];
                long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
                compile(compiler, fileManager, path);
                t0 = (System.currentTimeMillis()-t0);
                System.err.println("\tcompiling "+classes[i]+"="+t0+" ms");
                total+=t0;
            }
            System.err.println("Total "+total+" ms");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.err.println();        
    }

    private boolean compile(JavaCompiler compiler, StandardJavaFileManager fileManager, String toCompile) {
        long t0;
        List<String> plist = new ArrayList<>();
        PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(System.out);
        File javaFile = new File(toCompile);
        Iterable fileObjects=fileManager.getJavaFileObjects(javaFile);
        boolean ret=compiler.getTask(pw, fileManager, null, plist, null, fileObjects).call();
        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CompileTest ct = new CompileTest();
        ct.doCompile();
    }

}
```

Comment: Those numbers are too small to make a sensible comparison.

Comment: Seems to be a Windows problem. Why don't you try with Java 21?

Comment: Just printing currentTimeMillis() is not a valid benchmark.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java.

Comment: In my real code, wich is much more complex, the compilation time is multiplied by ten, with the same difference ratio between 8 and 17. For example, I had a compilation time of 3275 ms in JDK 8 and up to 9745 ms in JDK 17 for the same sources.

I can't use Java 21, because I'm working on a product which is tested in JDK 8 and JDK 17 (yes big gap..) and we can't test it for the moment on another JDK version.
By the way, I can try my tests case..

Comment: Have you tried excluding the project directory from your antivirus software?

Comment: It could work in java 21 since it work in 17 , maybe also try on another windows to see if it's a disk access problem (you could use virtualbox vm without antivirus) . Finally, if you made a big benchmark maybe diffuse this information in the question to make it less broad . (Interesting to see java manual call on the compiler though) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268305/what-is-an-indicator-that-a-question-is-too-broad-or-not

Comment: Thanks for your comments.. I've tried to exclude the project directory from the antivirus, with  no effect.

Comment: If you can’t change the implementation, you have to live with the implementation specific performance. However, you can compile all files at once instead of one by one, which will improve the performance significantly. Plus some cleanup, like not converting between `File` and `String` back and forth, not using `toLowerCase()` (which creates a new string each time) for case insensitive comparison, use `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1` instead of `Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")` and a lambda expression for the `FilenameFilter`, etc. Further, specifying the option `--release 8` may help a bit.

Comment: If you’re interested in implementation details, `JavaFileManager` implementation has been rewritten to use the `FileSystem` abstraction, which makes it simpler to treat jar files and module images the same way. Prior to Java 20, the was no [genuine support for `exist` queries](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html#exists(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.LinkOption...)) so probing the existence of files via `Files.exist` will query attributes and catch exceptions which is expensive. That’s why JDK 21’s performance is better again.